# Android Oauth2 to authenticate my Spring Server

Tags: android, spring-boot, authentication, oauth-2.0, bearer-token

I'm developing a Spring boot server for an exam.

I have followed [this](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-security-oauth2-social-login-part-1/) tutorial, so now I have a Spring boot server with MySQL, Social login with Google with OAuth2 and a react-js front-end. 
When I log in with react-js, I have in the header of my request "Authorization: Bearer ey...." and my REST API want this for the session.

Now I have to do the same thing in Android. I want to login with social login in my own server with OAuth2, obtain the AccessToken and put this in my request like in react. 
The problem is I don't know what to do. It is almost 5 days that I'm searching for a solution or a tutorial or a guide, but every link seems to be incomplete or using only social login with google server.

Can someone link me some guide or explain me the architecture of the thing that I want to do? 
I have tried to read the [google documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate#java) but it is not complete and there aren't any executable base project or repo's....

Thank you for reading.

**UPLOAD:** I've set up the Android App and I can log in and see my IdToken. What I can't understand is how to tell to my Spring server all the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Minute of Google Shows me [this](https://hackernoon.com/adding-oauth2-to-mobile-android-and-ios-clients-using-the-appauth-sdk-f8562f90ecff). 
In general there are many examples on Google how to integrate OAuth2 into a native application.

Comment: I have used qwant lol
Thank you, I will try it. I have searched for 5 days but I haven't find anything that I can understand (sure it is my fault)...

Comment: Thank you for your tutorial.
I set up the Spring server and the android app. I can log in with google and show my idToken. What I can't understand is how to give this to my custom spring server...

Comment: You should make a new question for this and tell how your login process is working. What i can imagine is, that you need to pass it as a endpoint to your server. Also please mark my answer so that other people can find the tutorial